# button can toggle boolean in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, webforms, boolean

trying to make button in asp.net and C# that change its text from "Show Edit" to "Hide Edit" and it will do more code in future like making text box visible and invisible so I can't use the short if statement.
first it tried to put a boolean to be like switch but it didn't worked.

```
if(isEditing)
{
    Button1.Text = "Show Edit";
    isEditing = false;
}
if(!isEditing)
{
    isEditing = true;
    Button1.Text = "Hide Edit";
}
```

this is the code inside the button method and the "isEditing" boolean is decelerated above in C# class and initialized with default value.
it is not working for some reason it just switch one time and it not change.

Comment: Are you stomping on something important in `Page_Load` like reinitializing `isEditing` to a default value or something along those lines? Check if you are correctly checking for the `Page.IsPostBack` condition.

Comment: The second `if` sees `isEditing` as always `false`, since you set it to `false` in the first `if`, if it isn't already `false`. Therefore `isEditing` will always be set to `true`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Ha didn't see that at first. That does look like the problem here.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes
the default value is false so in first run the second `if` will do its job and invert the value to true so in the next run the first `if` will run instead and invert the value again.

Comment: @TharwatMella Your are describing what  you want to happen, not what is actually happening. All you need to do here is set a break point and step through the code two times to check if the actual code matches your expectations. If they do not, use the debugger again to find the first time something doesn't match what you expect. Now you'd found a bug, so fix it. Repeat this until the actual behavior matches  your expectations. You can find a primer on debugger usage here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019 Good luck!

Comment: @TharwatMella: yes, but immediately after the first `if`, the second one runs, undoing what the first one did. It always runs because you have missed the `else` keyword. Without the `else` keyword, the two **if**s are just two independent statements that are executed in sequence. And btw., the second one is superfluous if you use an else part (see @TimSchmelter's answer).

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes
I didn't think it will be difficult
I tried every thing I used two `if` and `if/else` and `if/ else if`  and `Switch` statement.
but nothing work as I said they are all leading to the same result.
but with using break points and debugging I noticed that the default value which is initialized in the parent block (the class block) or in the (page load) is always being executed.
every time I press the button the page lode and the main class are executed.
that make the boolean value always has the same default value.

Comment: You might have to store this state in the [session variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178581(v=vs.100)) when working with ASP.NET

Answer (score 1):

I guess you wanted to use `else if` or simply `else` instead of a second `ìf` where you change the `isEditing` to `true` immediately:

```
if(isEditing)
{
    Button1.Text = "Show Edit";
    isEditing = false;
}
else
{
    isEditing = true;
    Button1.Text = "Hide Edit";
}
```

You could also use:

```
Button1.Text = isEditing ? "Show Edit" : "Hide Edit";
isEditing = !isEditing;
```

Comment: actually all this ways are leading to the same result which make the button work only for one time and the value of boolean is true.

I set a false value as default and put it in class block
in first button press it should take the second IF statement and the boolean will be true, in second button press it should take the first IF and the value will be iverted again and so on.
but for some reason it didn't work